# Comparing two datasources in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-binding

I have a gridview, bound to a datasource whose database table contains a foreign key that is associated with the database table that is used as the datasource for a dropdownlist.

What I want to do is if a certain `foreignKeyId` exists in `gridview.datasource`, to remove it from `dropdownlist.datasource`.

To give a clearer idea of what/why I want what I want, the user is able to add entries to the gridview (and therefore the datasource), but I don't want the user to be able to make more than one entry for a specific type. Is there a way that a linq query could do this?

pseudocode (note that I know *RemoveObjects()* is an invalid method)

```
var query = DataContext.Items.Where(item => item.TypeId == selectedTypeId);
dropDownList.DataSource.RemoveObjects(query);
```

Here is how I bind the dropdownlist, so maybe I could do something here to **not** get the items with already existing TypeId's?

```
dropDownList.DataSource = DataContext.Items.Select(items => new
                {
                    items.Name,
                    items.TypeId,
                }).ToList();
```

Any suggestions or answers would be great!

Comment: What is the nature of object you are creating in Select when you assign DataSource? It looks like dynamic type but property names are missing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx)

```
    dropDownList.DataSource.Except(query)
```

Comment: I think this won't work because items bound to dropDownList are of a dynamic type and not the type of items in DataContext.Items. So Except wont work.

Comment: @valipour it will depend on the default equality comparer. One could also implement their own IEqualityComparer and pass it in if using except is desirable over other options. Perhaps you want to add another option

Comment: I would say defining data source items as a named type (instead of dynamic) to make it more transparent and also having except to work explicit.

Comment: What about dropDownList.DataSource = DataContext.Items.Except(query).Select ( ...

Comment: @Jordan I was referring to the `var query` you had already set up